# How to choose the background color of video monitoring interface

Tags: usability, design, user-research, interface, color

Recently, I am working on the UI of video monitoring system, and it include images, table, infographic, and etc. I am really hesitated how to choose background color.

Many days ago, many good guys told me why i need to use dark color as background ([The question I ask before](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93992/why-do-video-monitoring-system-ui-use-a-dark-background)). But, I found out Youtube and some ither system like [Luxriot](http://www.luxriot.com/eng/products/vvca/?gclid=CI-okM2a4MwCFQomvQodHzMBMg) using light color as background. It make me so confused. Does anyone can tell me why someone use light color like Youtube and Luxriot, why someone use dark color. If I choose dark as background, why? If I choose light color, why?

Really appreciate!!

Answer (score 3):

And Apple uses white background for their videos on website. While using light background colors, make sure you apply shadows to the player so the visual content stands out.

[**Take a loot at the Video Player UX on Pinterest**](https://in.pinterest.com/edwardrmiller/video-player-ux/)

[**Here are some aspects of dark color**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/what-are-the-negative-and-positive-aspects-of-dark-color-scheme)